# Is there a way to specify CICD Pipeline target path in yaml file?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a Maven based project that is hosted on Gitlab, but does not exactly follow the Maven based layout :
The layout is as follows : 
*branch "example"*

```
-App
 - Service
  - SubService
   - src
    -main
     -java
      - Core.java
    - test
     -java
      - CoreTest.java
   -pom.xml
```

---

*As you can see, the actual Maven specific code is in SubService, not the root*

Now, when I have a commit on Core.java, I want to run a set of maven commands to build and test. 
However, I havent understood how to specify (in the Gitlab CI YAML file) to build and test the code found in **App/Service/SubService[/..]**

I have only been able to specify the branch - is there any way to specify a specific repository endpoint to test from in Gitlab ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Within your `.gitlab-ci.yml`-file, you can [specify the commands that should be run](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#script) in order to build your project.

You can e.g. `cd` to the directory `App/Server/SubService` and execute the maven build within this directory:

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
     -cd App/Server/SubService
    - mvn package
```